# How to load an array of objects in typescript

Tags: typescript

How do i convert this simple javascript to proper typescript syntax using a class with an "Add" method?

```
var i, rec;
var myArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    rec = { name: "john", age: i };
    myArray.push(rec);
}
```

I figured out how to at least define a variable, but I can't use an "Add" method to load it:

```
var myArray: { name: string; age: number }[] = [];
```

Here is my pathetic attempt with an Add method on a class:

```
class MyClass {
    name: string;
    age: number;

    add(inArg1: string, inArg2: number) {
        this.name = inArg1;
        this.age = inArg2;
    }
}

var myArray= new Array<MyClass>();

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    myArray.add("john", i);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the above answer does it's job, it is not reflecting the requirements of having a custom array for specific classes. As you are learning I want to share some of my experience in OOP, since I think this solution is providing you with more meaning.

1. You define a class which reflects your requirements of the object in the array:

   ```
   class MyClass {
       name: string;
       age: number;

      constructor(name: string, age: number) {
          this.name = name;
          this.age = age;
      }
   }
   ```
2. You define a custom array which extends the JavaScript array type.

   ```
   class MyArray<T> extends Array<T> {
       add(element: T) {
           this.push(element);
       }
   }
   ```

The `T` means you define a generic array which can hold any class you will provide when you create it. Furthermore you extend the JavaScript array type with a method `add`.

```
let array = new MyArray<MyClass>();
array.add(new MyClass('Ford', 20));
```

As you see in the creation of a new `MyArray` you are adding `MyClass` as a type argument. After that you can add objects from type `MyClass`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a constructor instead of a method and create new instances with new keyword inside the loop:

```
class MyClass {
    name: string;
    age: number;

    add(inArg1: string, inArg2: number) {
        this.name = inArg1;
        this.age = inArg2;
    }
}

var myArray= new Array<MyClass>();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.add('john',i);
    myArray.push(myClass);
}
```

Comment: Ufuk - Do you have a sample of how I would modify the above code to do this?

Comment: @Lambert What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your changes.  However, I would still prefer to have an "Add" method.  If the code becomes too wordy, I may just end up using the "Push" way.

Comment: @Lambert You realize that you defined the Add method on MyClass, not the array type right?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best answer to my original question, but it's what I ended up using because to me it's a less complicated way.  This is an example of loading an array of objects that contains a nested array of objects which is something that most projects I work on usually have.

```
interface mySubRecord {
    eyeColor: string;
    weight: number;
}

interface myRecord {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    more: mySubRecord[];
}

var i: number, rec: myRecord, subRec: mySubRecord[];
var myArray: myRecord[] = []; //Weird syntax here.

subRec = [{ eyeColor: "brown", weight: 118 }];

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    rec = { name: "john", age: i, more: subRec };
    myArray.push(rec);
}
```